# Registros de un usuario, que no registró nada en cierta fecha (mostrar el nombre y demás campos vacíos)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, html5, base-de-datos

Este es el código que tengo pero no se como traer los nombre de los usuarios y que los muestre con las fechas de las búsqueda realizada... solo me trae los que registraron algo en esa fecha y debo mostrar todos los usuarios día por día de las fechas de la búsqueda y los que no registraron nada que muestre solo el nombre y la fecha. Dejo una imagen de como se tendría que ver !

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['enviar1'])) {
    $busqueda11 = $busqueda1;
    $busqueda98 = $busqueda12;
    
    //consulta para traer los nombres de los usuarios
    $consultaNom = $con->query("SELECT DISTINCT `nome` FROM  `usuarios`");
    //consulta de fecha a fecha 
    $consulta = $con->query("SELECT * FROM  `usuarios` 
        WHERE `data` BETWEEN '$busqueda11'AND'$busqueda98'ORDER BY `data` ASC ");

    while($row = $consulta->fetch_array()){ 
    ?>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nome"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nomel"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["data"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orarioi"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orariof"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["tot"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nomel1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orarioi1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orariof1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["tot1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["notas"];?></div>
            <div class="botones">
            <a style="text-decoration:none;background-color: #4488EE;"class="botones1" 
                href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row["id_usuario"];?>">Aggiungi nota
            </a>
            <a style="text-decoration:none;background-color: #4488EE;"class="botones1" 
                href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row["id_usuario"];?>">Eliminare
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php 
    } 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no se entiende muy bien lo que quieres lograr, un simple if en la vista o tienes una relacion de dos tablas?, que stá fallando? tu consulta o la visualización?

Comment: primero gracias por responder !! la consulta no falla , pero solo me muestra los días en que registraron datos !!! solo me muestra en esa imagen a Palacios Maria , los demás los agregue yo de forma manual ! como puedo hacer para hacer una cosulta y traer todos los nombres de la base de datos y de ahi asignarlos a todas las fechas de la búsqueda y donde allá coincidencia de nombres y datos que los muestre y donde no que muestre el "nombre " la fecha en "date" y los demás campos que queden vacíos ?

Comment: no  me has resuelto nada, los datos que quieres mostrar estan en una sola tabla o estan relacionados? porque solo veo una consulta a una tabla y ahi no deberia tener confusion

Comment: solo están en una tabla ! gracias por tu ayuda  ..

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: como mostrar los campos vacios de un usuario que no tuvo actividad ese dia, mostrar  solo el nombre, con los campos vacios ya entiendo que si no tuvo actividad no muestra nada por no hay nada registrado , pero necesito mostrar el nombre la fecha y los cmpos vacios